# Javascript property reference and memory usage

Tags: javascript, object, memory, getter

I have this small piece of code, that adds `implement` function to `Object` (I know, not a good practice). It  copies properties of argument object (superobject) into the object, on which you call the method.

```
Object.prototype.implement = function(superobject) {
    var props = {};
    for (var key in superobject){
        if (superobject.hasOwnProperty(key) && !this.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
            props[key] = {
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true,
                get: this.implement.__get__(superobject, key),
                set: this.implement.__set__(key)
            };
        }
    Object.defineProperties(this, props);
    return this;
};

Object.prototype.implement.__get__ = function(superobject, key){
    return function(){return superobject[key];};
};

Object.prototype.implement.__set__ = function(key){
    return function(value){
        Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
            value: value,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true
        });
    };
};
```

By copying, it actually creates own property, but the value is reference to the property of the superobject. This is done by the property "getter". This example shows a simple usage:

```
var obj1 = {
    a:10
}

var obj2 = {
    b:20
}

obj1.implement(obj2)  // "implement" properties of obj2 to obj1

console.log(obj1.a) // -> 10
console.log(obj1.b) // -> 20

obj2.b = 21

console.log(obj1.a) // -> 10
console.log(obj1.b) // -> 21 -> it apperas to be reference to property b in obj2

obj1.hasOwnProperty("a") // -> true
obj1.hasOwnProperty("b") // -> true

obj1.b = 30;

console.log(obj1.b) // -> 30 //since obj1 has now "truly own" property b, it uses value of that instead of obj2's.
console.log(obj2.b) // -> 20
```

My question is this. After I call implement method on `obj1`, is `obj1.b` truly a reference? I mean - does `obj1.b` and `obj2.b` point to the same part of memory? Does the value `b:20` exist only in one place in memory? 
Is there maybe a good simple tool to see javascript's memory usage to confirm this?

Comment: Try comparing obj1.b and obj2.b with ===, if true then they are the same.

Comment: Please also note that there are various Javascript engines with different implementations. Ecmascript 5/6 doesn't specify every detail.This also applies to memory management.